# Distribution that describes n successes until one fail, in order.

Tags: probability, statistics, distribution-theory, binomial-distribution

I am trying to understand how to interpret the following:

If we have an unbiased coin flip and consider a head to be a "success" and a tail to be a "fail" we can interpret this as a Bernoulli experiment with p = 1/2. If we repeat n of these coin flips, which are independent we can distribute the following to a Binomial distribution.

Is a Binomial distribution n flips until the first fail? For example all of these "sequences" are valid in my problem:

'10'
'0'
'110' etc

but for example these are not allowed:

'01'
'001' etc

If the Binomial distribution is not the following (n successes in sequence until first fail, what distribution describes this?)

Sincerly a confused statistic student.

Comment: See the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).  In your problem, the roles of success and failure are reversed.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, Yes I also thought about this, but I am very unsure how to approach this with a reverse problem. I thought about doing 1 - geometric distribution, but I don't know if this yields a correct answer.

Comment: Nevermind I think I understand what you mean, @N.F.Taussig Thank you. I know how to solve my problem now, but is it correct to call this a "inverse"/"reverse" geometric distribution?

Comment: No?  You should just call heads "successes" and tails "fails" rather than doing it the other way of calling heads "fails" and tails "successes."  All you need to do is rephrase which are successes versus fails.  There is no need to rename the distribution.  The scenarios are not sufficiently different enough to warrant calling it a different distribution.

Comment: @JMoravitz Alright I understand, thank you.